# Creating multiple folders with the Box, Inc c# sdk throws "Parameter count mismatch." exception

Tags: c#, box-api

I have been running into a javascript error when I use the Box, Inc c# sdk to create multiple folders at once. I have been using a class consisting of a path and a list of strings for the paths of the child directories. When I call the CreateBoxFolders method however, it randomly throws a parameter count mismatch exception. I've so far been unable to determine why.

```
    private void CreateBoxFolders(string dir, long boxfolderid)
    {
        string[] dirnames = dir.Path.Split('\\');

        CreateBoxFolder(dirnames[dirnames.Count() - 1], boxfolderid);

        long id = GetFolderId(dirnames[dirnames.Count() - 1], boxfolderid);

        // This is a class with a list that stores the folder structure and path 
        dir.ChildDirectories.ForEach(x =>
            CreateBoxFolders(x, id));
    }

    private void CreateBoxFolder(string name, long parent)
    {
        _BoxManager.CreateFolder(name, parent, false);
    }


    private long GetFolderId(string name, long parent)
    {
        var folders = _BoxManager.GetFolderStructure(parent,
                  BoxSync.Core.Primitives.RetrieveFolderStructureOptions.OneLevel);
        long number = folders.Folder.Folders.Where(x => x.Name == name.Trim()).First().ID;
        return number;
    }
```

Comment: Which SDK you are using exactly? AFAIK there is no official C# SDK for Box.

Comment: Are you passing in an empty dir into your function?  Seems like the call dirnames.Count() would be unbounded for an empty dirnames array.

Comment: I'm using the C# SDK from the box github page [link](https://github.com/box/box-csharp-sdk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that one of your arrays is either null or empty.

```
long id = GetFolderId(dirnames[dirnames.Count() - 1], boxfolderid);
```

This line is likely at some point working with the root folder, where the id=0.   Folder 0 is a virtual folder that sits at the root of your account and doesn't have any directory structure.   Thus it is the root.  My suspicion (without being a C# programmer) is that this is evaluating down to

```
long id = ...(emptyarray[emptyarray.Count() -1], ...
```

I suspect that the count of an empty array may be either null or zero.  Null would be bad...

Comment: This appears to be close to the problem. When I fix this to ensure that no nulls get passed I get another exception: "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host". I'm wondering if this is being caused by the same block of code.